# Connect to open wifi network and fill in browser login mask with Powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, browser, connection, wifi

I am starting to learn about PowerShell and wanted to solve this problem for myself as a kind of exercise, but without success so far so I'm seeking help:

Every morning I am at the client site and connect to their WiFi (open) network. Then a login mask appears in the browser and I have to type in my individual username and password. Then I'm connected.

I would like to automate that in PowerShell or wanna know if that is possible at all.

What I got so far:

- I downloaded the respective WiFi profile as xml file (Wi-Fi-guestnet.xml)
- I found this code snippet to connect to the network automatically (Script is in the same directory as the xml file)

  ```
  netsh wlan add profile filename="$PSScriptRoot\Wi-Fi-guestnet.xml"
  ```

This doesn't work though, probably because I have to fill in additional credentials and it is not really "open".

Using PowerShell v5.1.x

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question and maybe I can give an answer .

You can ask powershell to open IE and then you can fill usename and password .

I have similar script that I used for similar thing .

I will try to find it and share .